# Invoking AWS Lamba with payload from AmazonLambdaClient

Tags: c#, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm running into issues successfully invoking a c# lambda function in AWS from a c# application using the [AmazonLambdaClient SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lambda/TLambdaLambdaClient.html).  I get an Invocation error from Lambda saying there was an unexpected character with no additional details.

I can successfully invoke the Lambda method from the Test Function window in Visual Studio sending in a serialized string of JSON so I'm not sure what the difference between how I'm invoking them.

For reference I'm using AWS' this documentation:

[AWS Lambda SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lambda/TLambdaLambdaClient.html)

[Invoke Method in SDK client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lambda/MLambdaLambdaInvokeInvokeRequest.html)

Lambda FunctionHandler:

```
public void FunctionHandler(string payload, ILambdaContext context)
{

    LambdaLogger.Log("Payload:" + payload);
    return;
}
```

Console App Invocation:

```
var _request = new Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeRequest { FunctionName = "ES-Test", Payload = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ID = _id }) };
Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeResponse _response = _lambda.Invoke(_request);
```

Cloud Watch Log:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line
>   1, position 1.: JsonReaderException at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString() at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader
>   reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader) at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )

Comment: Aaron, if you're still looking for a solution here, can you post a sample of your payload data? When I've gotten this error with json it was always related to malformed json that Newtonsoft was trying to parse.

Comment: @RyanGibbs the object is just a one property object where the property value is a unique identifier.   Id =“00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000”

Comment: Check how you're serializing the Json with Newtonsoft. From what you posted it looks like you are serializing an object { ID: '000etc' } but in your response you specify { Id: '000etc' }. Notice the difference in casing. You'll need to match the casing when you deserialize in your Lambda function as well.

Comment: Something additional to keep in mind is that you're creating an anonymous object with 'new { ID = _id }'. To illustrate this, look at this simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/persononfire/9nd8o32b/

Comment: I have the same issue, the lambda function works when the input payload is excaped and it is called from Visual Studio Eg: "{ \"id\": \"1\", \"OddOrEvenPostsResult\": 2}" but it does work work when you send the same escaped string payload through the test code. I have made sure that the casing matches